# How to reset recyclerview itemlist to start position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 3 buttons and a `Recyclerview`. On click of each button, I am updating the `Recyclerview` list. I am using the following way to update the Recyclerview list:

```
fun updateList(list: List<SortFilterItem>){
    itemList.clear()
    itemList.addAll(list)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
```

The problem is if I scroll the list to a certain position and then click on any of the `Button` the list is updated but the position is not reset to the start position. How can I reset the position of the `Recyclerview` when I update the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0); //Way I
layoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerView, null, 0); //Way II
```

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#getLayoutManager()

Answer (score 1):

Try `yourLayourManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,0)`, this will scroll until satisfy the offset.

or `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position)`

Answer (score 1):

just add line into your button click when you update your code

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
```